# IOException Unhandled Splash screen

Tags: c#

After the splash screen it shows this error.

[image: problem]
[image: problem]

Comment: as it said, it cannot find the image splashscreen.jpg

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code on this site, copy and paste the code in to the question, press the `{ }` button on the tool bar to format it if nessesary. Also don't post screenshots of exceptions, press the text that says *"Copy exception detail to the clipboard"* in the exception window and paste that in to your question too. You can wrap the text with `<pre> </pre>` so it keeps its formatting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the `Build Action` in `Properties` panel to `Resource`.
2. Clean your project (it's important to catch the new build action)
3. Fix the following line:

`SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen("splashscreen.jpg");`

to

`SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen("media/splashscreen.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the image build action is set to embedded  resource and then pass the resource identifier to the splash screen constructor. This is the default namespace of your application plus the path to your resource. E.g. "MyNamespace.Media.Splashscreen.jpg"